Concrete basement wall transition to plywood strip on floor joists
I'm covering up the space between a floor joist and a concrete wall in an old house.
See picture:

Question is, what kind of transition make sense here?
I guess it would been easier to use drywall (instead of plywood) and then perhaps mud in a corner.
But if not using drywall, what to use?

So screw 1/4" (6mm) (or thicker) drywall to the plywood and proceed with it being drywall.

Crown molding? :)

If you want it to be the wood showing up there, and you have a plaster wall surface, then plaster up to it (first cleaning off the evidently loose plaster that's there now;) masking the edge of the wood at the depth you're planning to apply plaster to the wall surface and using a plaster ground to help guide the application there.

Thanks! What kind of "plaster ground" would you use? I'm not sure I know what that is.

A plaster ground is a bit of metal trim (usually) that's used to guide the troweling of the edge of an area to be plastered. It's a pretty standard thing from a place that sells plastering supplies. Similar to the function of an "L-bead" for drywall, but not the same thing.
